# Best practice for using dates as versions in Maven

Tags: java, maven

We are creating a jar that fetches descriptions for ECUs and Faults codes.

```
DescriptionFinder finder = new DescriptionFinder();
String response = finder.findEcmDesc("43");
```

The descriptions get loaded from a big property file that is maintained by some engineers.  This property file gets updated 3 times a year.

This is a standalone jar and we want to update it 3 times a year and think a date for a version is a good idea.

```
 <artifactId>pfm-common-descriptions</artifactId>
 <version>2020.5.1</version>
 <name>pfm-common-descriptions</name>
```

Pretty much every thing I read says it is best practice to not use a date, but I am pretty sure this is the instance when it is a good thing.  We want our users to upgrade to the latest jar.  This would be a visual reminder to do that if it is too old.

Here are some of my ideas:

- 2020.5.1
- 2020.5.1_1 (date and version just in case)
- 2020APR01

I'm guessing our customers could use the RELEASE keyword:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>blah.blah.blah</groupId>
  <artifactId>pfm-common-descriptions</artifactId>
  <version>RELEASE</version> **(this has actually been deprecated!)**
</dependency>
```

But they may not. And a date would still be a great indicator of age. We are setting up notifications as to when JFrog (our maven repo) gets a change.

Thoughts?  Should I add a version to the date? What format do you use?

Comment: Common practice is to use Semantic Versioning (https://semver.org/) - what you need to remember is that when a version is out in Production is not when the build was made, or tested/approved, etc. So which date to use? Also, what if you have two or more builds a day? We use timestamps (in miliseconds) to identify which build is which but only *after* a semver (i.e. 5.4.3-timestamp.jar)

Comment: Having said that, there are software packages with semi-fixed release dates (i.e. once a quarter) that use this date strategy for their releases (i.e. 2020.1 for the 1st quarter of 2020, patches to it still being 2020.1.1 ) and they use this versioning for all their external (marketing) versioning.  Internally (for build systems) they use something close to semver + plus unique build-number (i.e. 20.72539.15-323423)

Comment: First discourage usage of `RELEASE` as already mentioned it is deprecated and should not being used cause it's not reproducible. Furthermore You could of course use things like `2020.5.1`...I recommend **not** to use `2020APR01` ...If you make a change on `2020.5.1` you should have `2020.5.2` or going a way `2020.5.1.0` and you can use the last `0` as indicator for bug fixes...etc. The date versioning does not correctly show compatibility etc. which semver does ...

Comment: Using semver and adding a timestamp violates semver...if you change something it's new version like `5.4.3` and a change on it `5.4.4`..the question is: new function than ´5.5.0` bugfix `5.4.4` breaking `6.0.0`...

Answer (score 1):

In general, best practice is to use [semver](https://semver.org/) for versions. But some don't do that.

If you follow semver, it would be nice to keep track on what has changed, have kind of [CHANGELOG.md](https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.0.0/) so that your users can be aware of what new things are added to a new version and make a decision if it's worth updating.

Having a date in version doesn't really add too much sense, from my point of view.

Add a notification when a new version comes? It may be done with semver.

Make them aware of how old is their current version? Each jar has this meta information, and a user can open your CHANGELOG.md and see what was added since their current version is released.

So I don't see any reasons why semver doesn't fit here.

Comment: Forgot my Changelog.  Thanks!